# How can I obtain the complement of list of indexes in Julia?

Tags: julia, filtering, list-comprehension

Suppose that I have a variable `i = [1,3,5]`, which was obtained when I applied a filter to an array. Now, suppose that this array has 10 elements, and I'd like to obtain the "complement" indexes. I mean, I want to obtain `ic = [2,4,6,7,8,9,10]`.

Is there a clean and short way of obtaining this complement list of indexes?

I mean, I can do this with a regular loop, but is there a way of doing this with list comprehension?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to get all elements in `1:10` that aren't in `i`. So using list comprehension:

```
julia> i = [1,3,5];

julia> ic = [x for x ∈ 1:10 if x ∉ i]
7-element Array{Int64,1}:
  2
  4
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
```

You can type ∈ in REPL with `\in` <kbd>Tab</kbd>. ∉ can be achieved with `\notin` <kbd>Tab</kbd>. If you're coding in an environment that don't allow this, you can just copy from here or type one of these instead:

```
julia> ic = [x for x in 1:10 if !(x in i)]
```

```
julia> ic = [x for x in 1:10 if !in(x, i)] # operators are functions
```

---

### Performance

If you care about performance, here the benchmark:

```
julia> @benchmark ic = [x for x ∈ 1:10 if x ∉ i]
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  288 bytes
  allocs estimate:  4
  --------------
  minimum time:     462.274 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      471.168 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        497.947 ns (2.86% GC)
  maximum time:     13.115 μs (95.25% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     197
```

Answer (score 14):

If you care about performance you can also consider:

```
julia> @benchmark deleteat!([1:10;], $i) # indices must be unique and sorted
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  160 bytes
  allocs estimate:  1
  --------------
  minimum time:     53.798 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      60.790 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        71.125 ns (1.76% GC)
  maximum time:     618.946 ns (77.28% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     987
```

and

```
julia> @benchmark (x = trues(10); x[$i] .= false; findall(x)) # if Bool-array is enough for you you can skip the last step to save 50% of time
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  272 bytes
  allocs estimate:  3
  --------------
  minimum time:     124.863 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      134.033 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        157.668 ns (6.84% GC)
  maximum time:     3.000 μs (95.44% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     905
```

vs earlier proposed:

```
julia> @benchmark ic = [x for x ∈ 1:10 if x ∉ $i]
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  288 bytes
  allocs estimate:  4
  --------------
  minimum time:     170.714 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      196.571 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        222.510 ns (4.43% GC)
  maximum time:     3.078 μs (91.01% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     700
```

and

```
julia> @benchmark setdiff($[1:10;], $i)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  672 bytes
  allocs estimate:  7
  --------------
  minimum time:     504.145 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      514.508 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        589.584 ns (2.75% GC)
  maximum time:     8.954 μs (90.69% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     193
```

and (custom implementation from the other post)

```
julia> @benchmark mysetdiff($[1:10;], $i)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  144 bytes
  allocs estimate:  1
  --------------
  minimum time:     44.748 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      46.869 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        52.780 ns (1.75% GC)
  maximum time:     431.919 ns (88.49% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     990
```

Comment: It should be `mysetdiff($[1:10;], $i)` not `mysetdiff([1:10;], $i)`. Then you'll get proper 1 allocation and 46ns execution time.

Comment: Ah - right, because your is not in-place as opposed to `deleteat!`.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `setdiff` function

```
julia> x = [1, 3, 5];
julia> y = collect(1:10);
julia> setdiff(y, x)
7-element Vector{Int64}:
  2
  4
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
```

Performance-wise, loop-based implementation is better, because we can take into account that new indices are a subset of the original

```
function mysetdiff(y, x)
    res = Vector{eltype(y)}(undef, length(y) - length(x))
    i = 1
    @inbounds for el in y
        el ∈ x && continue
        res[i] = el
        i += 1
    end

    res
end
```

and comparison

```
using BenchmarkTools

@btime [z for z ∈ $y if z ∉ $x]
# 141.893 ns (4 allocations: 288 bytes)
@btime setdiff($y, $x)
# 477.056 ns (8 allocations: 688 bytes)
@btime mysetdiff($y, $x)
# 46.434 ns (1 allocation: 144 bytes)
```

Answer (score 7):

Since you already used filtering, do it for the reverse too. Or if you have the function that you used to get `i`, you can just negate that to get the complement set of indices.

```
julia> i = [1,3,5];

julia> filter(x -> x ∉ i, 1:10)
7-element Array{Int64,1}:
  2
  4
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
```

---

#### Benchmarks

```
@benchmark filter(x -> x ∉ i, 1:10)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  304 bytes
  allocs estimate:  2
  --------------
  minimum time:     501.036 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      511.399 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        546.609 ns (1.26% GC)
  maximum time:     7.516 μs (92.31% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     193
```

#### Reference solution

```
@benchmark ic = [x for x ∈ 1:10 if x ∉ i]
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  288 bytes
  allocs estimate:  4
  --------------
  minimum time:     626.036 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      646.154 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        692.179 ns (2.72% GC)
  maximum time:     26.065 μs (95.43% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     169
```

Answer (score 6):

One more worth-knowing-syntax to add to the list (although not too fast) from the `InvertedIndices` packages (commonly it also gets loaded together with `DataFrames`):

```
(1:10)[Not(i)]
```

```
julia> @benchmark (1:10)[Not($i)]
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  1.42 KiB
  allocs estimate:  39
  --------------
  minimum time:     1.130 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      1.320 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        1.713 μs (5.05% GC)
  maximum time:     324.000 μs (98.81% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     10
```

Comment: `Not` actually comes from InvertedIndices